# Chromecast tablet in portrait orientation to a TV in portrait orientation

Tags: chromecast

While using an app in Portrait mode, I want to display it on a TV that is also in portrait (i.e., I will mount the TV on its side), so the full tablet screen will fill the full TV.

I have tried Chromecast app but there is no option to force the screen to stay horizontal. Has anyone tried this?  Does the app have to be coded to directly cast the app/screen onto the TV?

Comment: Please note that development questions are off-topic here.  I've edited the question to reflect that, since I believe it is a reasonable end-user question as well.  You can ask specific Android development questions on [SO].

Comment: Here is an answer to a similar question on SO: [Can I cast on portrait mounted screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395221/can-i-cast-on-portrait-mounted-screen). While it is more developer focused, it does have an answer that explains it without any code.